# Expandable memory of devices

Tags: storage, insufficient-memory

Mobile phones or tablets come with limits like it has expandable memory of 32, 64, etc GB. I was wondering how this is determined? Does it mean that higher capacity sd cards won't work or this limitation is due to performance reasons? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Our phones/tablets comes with 2 types of memory:

Internal memory(can't be expanded)

External memory(that is expandable)

If a certain manufacturer says that your handset comes with an expandable memory of 32 GB, means you can insert a 32 GB SD card in it.Now , if your device has 8 GB internal memory,that overall you get 32+8 GB space.

Coming to the second part of your question, if you insert a 64 GB SD card in a handset mentioned above in answer, it wont support it.There is a limit to the amount of memory a particular phone can handle. SD cards come in a variety of flavors. And if your device isn't able to handle a particular flavor of storage technology, it won't accept higher capacity cards.

There are different SD card flavors as in :

**SDHC**(*Secure Digital High Capacity*), Cards using this technology can hold between 4GB and 32GB of data.

**SDXC**(*Secure Digital Extended Capacity*), which can hold between 64GB and 2TB of data.

You can learn more about these flavors [here](https://www.shutterbug.com/content/sd-memory-cards-everything-youve-ever-wanted-know-about-sd-cards-were-afraid-ask)